# Can we divide two terms in finding solution for Linear Inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, fractions, absolute-value

> Solve the following inequality.$$\frac{|x-2|}{x-2}>0$$

If $x$ is greater than or equal to $2$, it becomes:
$\frac{x-2}{x-2}>0$,
which can become $1>0$, which is true for all $x>2$ for when $x=2$,its value will become undefined. Is my solution correct?

Comment: Looks ok so far. What about when $x < 2$?

Comment: when x<2, the solution will be 1<0. So,it'll be false.

Comment: Thank You everyone for their help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just three cases:

$x>2$ gives $1>0$, which is true.

$x<2$ gives $-1>0$, which is wrong and

$x=2$, which  is impossible.

After all these things we got the answer: $(2,+\infty)$.

Comment: I get it. In an alternative method of it,though,the wavy curve method,how can I solve this inequality via that  method ? And can i always divide terms like this while finding solution?

Comment: @Dilin Finn It depends on the inequality, which we need to solve. But for the expressions like $\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}$ I think  it's better to check cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you solution is OK.

You could also notice that $|x-2| \ge 0$ and $x \ne 2$ as denominator cannot be $0$.

Thus in order for your whole equation to be greater than $0$, since the numerator is positive, it has to be the case that the denominator is also positive, which gives us the answer: